# How to send data from one razor page to another?

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework

I am trying to send some data from one razor page to another. For my scenario a user is trying to register an account.  When they submit their info they have a confirmation code sent to their email (in this case the 'email' is stored in a file in C:/) then when they go back to the webapp to input the code and confirm it then the account is registered and is sent to the next page.  I am having trouble knowing what user is currently operating on the webapp.   So, on the registration page they input their info then a code is generated and they are sent to a 'confirmation' page where they put the code BUT when they reach the next page I am unable to know who's confirmation code is the correct one for the current user, I need to pass either the userID that just registered or the actually confirmation code to the confirmationPage? I think you can save the user information by opening a session but I only wanted to start the session after their account is fully registered and confirmed.

I believe you can use ViewData in this scenario but when I tried using ViewData the object sent to the next page was null and did not have the information I needed

Register Model

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        readonly DatabaseContext _context;
        public IAccountService accountService;
        public RegisterModel(IAccountService _accountService, DatabaseContext context)
        {
            this.accountService = _accountService;
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public VisUser _VisUser { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Email mails { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter User Password"), DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        // Generate a random password    
        public string RandomCode()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append(RandomString(4, true));
            builder.Append(RandomNumber(1000, 9999));
            builder.Append(RandomString(2, false));
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        // Generate a random string with a given size    
        public string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            if (lowerCase)
                return builder.ToString().ToLower();
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        // Generate a random number between two numbers    
        public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }

        public ActionResult OnPost()
        {
            _VisUser.ConfirmationCode = RandomCode();
            var visUser = _VisUser;
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            if(visUser.UserPassword.CompareTo(ConfirmPassword) == 1)
            {

                visUser.UserId = 0;
                var result = _context.Add(visUser);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                SendEmail();

                TempData["ConCode"] = visUser.ConfirmationCode;

                return RedirectToPage("/Account/ConfirmationCode");
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task SendEmail()
        {
            using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                mails.To = _VisUser.Email;
                mails.From = "danny@Vispires.com";
                mails.Subject = "Registration Confirmation Code";
                mails.Body = _VisUser.ConfirmationCode;

                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
                smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"c:\temp";
                var msg = new MailMessage
                {
                    Body = mails.Body,
                    Subject = mails.Subject,
                    From = new MailAddress(mails.From)
                };
                msg.To.Add(mails.To);
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);

            }
        }
    }
```

Confirmation Code Model:

```
public class ConfirmationCodeModel : PageModel
    {

        readonly DatabaseContext _context;
        public IAccountService accountService;
        public ConfirmationCodeModel(IAccountService _accountService, DatabaseContext context)
        {
            this.accountService = _accountService;
            _context = context;
        }

        public string ConCode { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Confirmation Code")]
        public string ConfirmCode { get; set; }


        public ActionResult OnPost(string ConfirmCode)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            if (ConCode == ConfirmCode)
            {
                //change isvalid and start session
                return RedirectToPage("/CreatePortfolio");
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
```

Confimration Code View:

```
@page
@using Visportfolio.Models @*namespace*@
@model Visportfolio.Pages.Account.ConfirmationCodeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ConfirmationCode";
}

<h1>Code Authentication</h1>

<h3>Enter Code Here:</h3>

@{
    if (TempData["ConCode"] != null)
    {
        var ConCode = TempData["VisUser"] as string;
    }
}

<form method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="ConfirmCode"></label>
            <input asp-for="ConfirmCode" class="form-control" />
            <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="ConfirmCode"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

In the end of RegisterModel > OnPost method I create the ViewData do hold the confirmation code.  Then I tried to receive it in the top of the confirmation code view.  Then when I try to access it in that page's OnPost the confirmation code is null.

Comment: Try hidden field to hold ConCode on Confirmation view as: <input asp-for="ConCode" type="hidden" value="@ConCode" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your scenario, that you want to register user and send confirmation code to its email or phone, storing confirmation code in ViewData, Session, ViewBag, TempData or transfer it between razor pages is not good idea. If your user close its browser window, you will lose registration code. You should store this code in a Distributed Cache or Memory Cache with a specific key like UserId, UserEmail or UserPhoneNumber for 60 seconds or more. Also you can store this code in a database but storing it in a cache is a better way.

Comment: Currently the confirmation code is stored in the database along along with a Validated column.  When a user registers their record in the database has their username, password, ... , confirmation code, valid column.  If the user never confirmed their code then their valid column remains 0, if it is validated then the valid column is 1.  So, all I would need is for matching user and confirmation code is UserId.  Is there a way to pass on the UserId of the user that just tried to register?

Comment: If you send an email to your user, also you can send a link with title "Click to confirm" or something else, and in your link is a url of your site : <a href="http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/ConfirmPage?email=YOUSEREMAIL&code=SENTCODE" , in ConfirmPage, get data from querystring and compare it with stored data. If not, Just send userId or useremail in your way to ConfirmPage (such as ViewData, querystring or somthing else) and set it to a hidden input in a form tag, and also an empty input tag for activation code.